# gcc c Compiler error

Tags: c, gcc

When attempting to compile

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

printf("Hello World");

return 0;

}
```

I get the following errors with Solaris11 gcc:

1. hello.c:4:23: error: expected expression before ';' token
2. hello.c:6:1: error: expected ';' before '}' token

Visual C++ can compile this code.

Comment: "Visual basic" -> "Visual C++" ?

Comment: I've spruced the question up a little. I have no idea why it doesn't work!

Comment: Cannot reproduce on GCC 6.3: http://ideone.com/UzYNuE (code copy-pasted from the question) - maybe you have some "invisible" symbols somewhere?

Comment: @Bathsheba - The greek question mark springs to mind http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/037e/index.htm

Comment: @StoryTeller: Odd that MSVC handles it though.

Comment: Can not reproduce on gcc-5.4.0-1.x86_64. The source code in the question is not an exact reproduction of the source code presented to the compiler. (That my not be the OP's fault -- no idea what the SO edit box does with pasted Unicode special chars.) There are other possible problems -- what would gcc do with non break spaces etc.?

Comment: @Bathsheba - It could very well be an encoding issue. If the file was saved in MSVC and then transferred unmodified to Solaris...

Comment: I have, as part of my standard test suite, a [tool](https://srv7.svn-repos.de/dev34/main/jaws/trunk/tools/check.cpp.in) that checks all source files for strict ASCII-7-ness (both filename and content). While many compilers nowadays would *accept* UTF-8 input, I think issues like these are worth binding yourself to the strictest possible standards....

Comment: I put the original code back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the naive reader, what you have in the question is valid C.

However, in order to achieve maximum portability, C compilers are allowed to be extremely fussy about the *characters* that you are allowed to type into your editor as a candidate for compilation.

I suspect that you have a character in the file that is not part of the ASCII set.

I suggest you re-type the code from scratch, using no other character than ASCII, and watch the error disappear.

Once you've done that, "diff" that with your original version.

Comment: You can also copy and paste from the question -- the SO editing tools appear to have sanitized whatever encoding impurity was there.

Answer (score 3):

the '；' in line four (the `return` statement) is not a standard ';'.

Comment: What did you use for the non-standard  '；' ?

Comment: @Bathsheba Roll it back!

Comment: Honest I didn't touch the actual code. In its original form the question was of rather poor quality.

Comment: @Bathsheba And you didn't even correct the "Complier" error! ;-) But perhaps on purpose -- it's a rather cute pun.